# CoreData and JSON mappers

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data

I was thinking about using **CoreData** `NSManagedObject` subclasses with json mappers but I'm using **DCKeyValueObjectMapping** and it doesn't seem to support using `NSManagedObject` subclasses.

Then again, I'm new to iOS so this may be not possible at all, but still I want to know how people handle it. For all I've researched, you don't seem to be able to instantiate a `NSManagedObject` subclass using `alloc init`, since you need to initialize it calling `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` and those 2 params doesn't seem to have setters methods.

So is there any way to use a single model class for both purpose, **CoreData** and `JSON` mapping

Answer (score 0):

[RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) may be useful (mapper can be used separately). Also there is KZPropertyMapper.